# how to set a variable in startevent in alfresco?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I want to get the property value `mcwf:status` from the model in `startevent`.
Then I need to pass the value of `mcwf:status` to other forms.

Below is the code, it is not printing variable,
it seems that the part of extensionElement has not been run?

The snippet of the bpmn diagram:

```
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start" activiti:formKey="mcwf:submitReviewTask">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
                        var newstatus = task.getVariableLocal('mcwf_status');
                        execution.setVariable('mcwf_newstatus', newstatus);
                        logger.log("AAAAAAAAA      " + newstatus);
                    ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
```

The snippet of the model file:

```
<aspect name="mcwf:status">
            <title>Status</title>
            <properties>
                <property name="mcwf:status">
                    <title>Status</title>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <default>0</default>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint type="LIST">
                          <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                            <value>100</value>
                            <value>200</value>
                            </list>
                          </parameter>
                        </constraint>
                    </constraints>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </aspect>
```

If I change the `startevent` to `usertask`, then I copy the code of extensionElements and paste instead of it, and don't know why it can be work properly.

Comment: not able to understand your last statment

Comment: i mean to use <usertask> instead of <startevent>, the above issue can be resolved. however, i need to get the variable from the startevent form and then pass the value to the next form which is a usertask

Comment: can you put the code of other form as well.

Comment: you mean the share-config-custom or the model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code snippet which is working for me for using variable in next task.

```
 <startEvent id="startevent2" name="Start" activiti:initiator="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="aw:TransportManager">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string>
            <![CDATA[
              execution.setVariable('aw_vehicle_number',                                                       task.getVariable('aw_vehicle_number'));
              execution.setVariable('aw_reg_number', task.getVariable('aw_reg_number'));
              execution.setVariable('bpm_workflowDescription', task.getVariable('bpm_workflowDescription'));             
              execution.setVariable('aw_finance_comments',task.getVariable('bpm_comment'));
           ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
         </activiti:executionListener>
     </extensionElements>
</startEvent>
```

Change activiti:taskListener  to activiti:executionListener.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! we cannot use taskListener in startEvent and should use executionListener